# Array.prototype.join not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have used the code snippet like below in my working scenario. It’s working fine in IE's latest versions but join function is not working in IE 8 Version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var str = "TEST\n";
            var lines = str.split(/\r?\n/).join("\r\n");
            debugger;        
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How to resolve this problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: `join` is supported from IE5.5, so something else is going on.

Comment: I'm guessing that older versions of IE have trouble matching a regex across a newline boundary.  In the back of my mind I remember issues like that in IE from awhile ago.  Can't remember the exact specifics.

Comment: The above code results in a [four-char string in IE 8, and a six-char string in IE 11](http://jsfiddle.net/eeLkLc78/). Is this what you mean by it not working?

Comment: Yes Jonathan Sampson

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your particular example would rather be the `split()` function, not the `join()`. The `split()` is what behaves differently between JScript 6 (IE8) and later JScript versions in that the length of the resulting array is different if the separator actually ends or begins the string. In this case, the `<null>` item is dropped, meaning:

> JScript 6:
>   "TEST\n".split("\n").length equals 1
>
> JScript 6+:
>   "TEST\n".split("\n").length equals 2

Again, in your example, this means that the `join()` in IE8 is performed on an array containing just one element.

If instead you use `replace()` --which seems a better option anyway-- you can overcome this problem, i.e. `str.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n")`.

Comment: In my working scenorio  str.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n") is not working . Is there any other way to resolve the split problem in IE8

Comment: Surely, but you need to explain what's going on better. Why is `replace()` not an option? **Edit**: Ey..? You're not the OP - Maybe you should ask your own question ;)